# Zend context switching json response

Tags: json, zend-framework

I am using context switching to get json response in Zend framework

This is the code I am using in init function in controller

```js
$this->_helper->contextSwitch()
                ->addActionContext('index', array('xml', 'json'))
                  ->setAutoJsonSerialization(true)
                    ->initContext();
```

In some other method I have doctrine_collection of data which I want as json response.

Code is

```
$pm = new ProfileMessage();
$flirts = $pm->fetchLastMessages($this->_member->user_id, "0,1", 
                                            Labels_MessageType::FLIRT, 5, 0);

$this->view->flirts = $flirts;
```

But for response I am getting an empty json string.

```
{"flirts":{}}
```

What I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: WHat kind of return value is $flirts?

Comment: Sorry for a late response, it returns Doctrine_Collection, and $flirts->toArray() seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to ensure $flirts is an array or serializable object:

```
php > $user = new Model_User();
php > $user->setId(10);
php > echo json_encode($user);
{} //output is empty

/* Convert the object to array */
php > echo json_encode($user->toArray());
{"_id":10} //output not empty

/* Trying a simple object */
php > $simple = new stdClass();
php > $simple->something = 'else';
php > echo json_encode($simple);
{"something":"else"} //output not empty
```

Comment: Thanks, $flirts->toArray() is OK